# PHP Print Function Escape

Tags: php, security, php-printer

```
<?php print('GET');
```

If I have the following WHERE `GET` is a `GET` parameter, is it possible to escape this for nefarious purposes i.e. can it be hacked?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are wanting `htmlspecialchars()` / `htmlentities()`?

Comment: Nothing automaticlly treats a string as a variable name.

Comment: My bad.... I misunderstood `WHERE GET is a GET parameter`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `'GET'` in quotes, it's a string literal. The fact that you have parameter `$_GET['GET']` is not relevant -- when you print a literal, it just prints that string, it doesn't try to treat it as a variable, or the index in an array, or anything else.

So that `print` statement is perfectly safe.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. What did you add, and where?